# need to create a new hidden div that shows after a onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that displays experiences. I want to create the option of showing a box ontop of my experiences with the different options they can do when they click an experience. I have different options for each experience.

This is my experiences

[image]

and I want to create a box like this with the corresponding images of each experience.

[image]

This is my experience component

```
    import React, { memo, useCallback } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import clsx from 'clsx';

import Popper from '@material-ui/core/Popper';
import gastronomia from 'assets/experiences/gastronomia.jpg';
import productos from 'assets/experiences/productos.jpg';
import giftcard from 'assets/experiences/giftcard.jpg';
import diversion from 'assets/experiences/diversion.jpg';
import deporte from 'assets/experiences/deporte.jpg';
import belleza from 'assets/experiences/belleza.jpg';
import gastronomiaExperiences from 'data/gastronomia';
import productosExperiences from 'data/productos';
import giftcardExperiences from 'data/giftcard';
import diversionExperiences from 'data/diversion';
import deporteExperiences from 'data/deporte';
import bellezaExperiences from 'data/belleza';

// Proptypes definitions to the component.
const propTypes = {
  /** Custom root className. */
  className: PropTypes.string,
};

// Default props definitions.
const defaultProps = {
  className: null,
};

// Component's styles
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'block',
    margin: '0 auto',
    maxWidth: '50%',
    [theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
      maxWidth: '70%',
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
      maxWidth: '100%',
    },
    '& .experiences-column': {
      display: 'inline-block',
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      textAlign: 'center',
      '&.col1': {
        width: '36.31%',
        [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
          width: 'initial',
        },
      },
      '&.col2': {
        width: '63.69%',
        [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
          width: 'initial',
        },
      },
      '& .experience': {
        padding: 2,
        position: 'relative',
        '& img': {
          width: '100%',
          display: 'block',
        },
        '& .experience-title': {
          position: 'absolute',
          bottom: 30,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          textAlign: 'center',
        },
      },
    },
  },
}), { name: 'ExperiencesStyle' });



/**
 * Component used to render a grid of experiences.
 *
 * @param {object} props - The component's props.
 * @returns {object} React element.
 */
const Experiences = memo(
  (props) => {
    const { className } = props;
    const classes = useStyles(props);
const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const handleClick = event => {
    setAnchorEl(anchorEl ? null : event.currentTarget);
  };

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const id = open ? 'simple-popper' : undefined;

    const experience = useCallback((img, title) => (
      <div className="experience" aria-describedby={id} onClick={handleClick} onClick={() => setAnchorEl(!anchorEl)}>
        <img
          data-sizes="auto"
          className="lazyload"
          data-src={img}
          alt={title}
        />
        <div className="experience-title">
          <Typography
            color="textSecondary"
            variant="subtitle2"
            className="highlight highlight1"
            display="inline"
          >
            { title }
          </Typography>
        </div>
      </div>

    ), []);

    return (
      <div className={clsx(classes.root, className)}>
        <div className="experiences-column col1">
          {experience(gastronomia, 'GASTRONOMÍA')}
          {experience(giftcard, 'GIFT CARD')}
          {experience(deporte, 'DEPORTE')}
        </div>
        <div className="experiences-column col2">
          {experience(productos, 'PRODUCTOS')}
          {experience(diversion, 'DIVERSIÓN')}
          {experience(belleza, 'BELLEZA')}
        </div>
        <Popper id={id} open={open} anchorEl={anchorEl}>
          <div className={classes.paper}>
            <p>Array of images here depending on category </p>
          </div>
        </Popper>
      </div>
    );
  },
);

// Component proptypes.
Experiences.propTypes = propTypes;

// Component default props.
Experiences.defaultProps = defaultProps;

export default Experiences;
```

I am complete lost on how to start this task. I am new to react

Comment: Ok, so after click on experience should show pink div with more information?

Comment: yes exactly. The information are images and the number of images depends on the experience

Comment: i'ill try .....

Comment: ok thanks I am really completely lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so

1. Delete experience from Experiences.
2. Add array of object - of your experiences

> ```
> const iterateExperience = [
>     {img: gastronomia, title: 'GASTRONOMIA' },
>     {img: productos, title: 'PRODUCTOS' },
> ];
> ```

3. Later map it like this:

> ```
>   <div className={clsx(classes.root, className)}>
>          {iterateExperience.map((experience, index) => (
>         <div key = {index}>
>            <Experience img = {experience.img} title = {experience.title}/>
>         </div>
> ))}
> </div>
> ```

4. Create Child Component - Experience:

> ```
> const Experience = (props) => {
>
>   const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(true)
>
>     return (
>       <div onClick={() => setClicked(!clicked)} 
>       className={clicked ? 'experience' : 'experience-clicked'}
>       >
>         <img
>           data-sizes="auto"
>           className="lazyload"
>           data-src={props.img}
>           alt={props.title}
>         />
>         <div className="experience-title">
>           <Typography
>             color="textSecondary"
>             variant="subtitle2"
>             className="highlight highlight1"
>             display="inline"
>           >
>           {props.title}
>           </Typography>
>         </div>
>       </div>
>     );
>   }
>
>   export default Experience
> ```

---

And if You wan't render the different component based on click, just add in **Experience** (You can also apply another style - whatever you want)

```
const Experience = (props) => {

  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(true)

    return (
      <div onClick={() => setClicked(!clicked)}  className='experience'>

      {clicked ? 
      <div>
        <img
          data-sizes="auto"
          className="lazyload"
          data-src={props.img}
          alt={props.title}
        />

        <div className="experience-title">
          <Typography
            color="textSecondary"
            variant="subtitle2"
            className="highlight highlight1"
            display="inline"
          >
          {props.title}
          </Typography>
        </div>
        </div>
    : 
    <p>Another Component</p>}
    </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: doesnt this just say that item is clicked and turn the item to pink... I need to open a new div over the other divs and display the images that are a list of places you can do the experiences... Sorry but I am lost

Comment: based on this mechanism - the clicked state - you are able to render one or the other component i trying optimize it

Comment: Sorry but I am still lost..... I want to import an array of images for each experience and display this list in a div for each experience but display this div over the other divs when this experience is selected... how does it get and show the images in a div when the experience is clicked

Comment: @NaNodine it works now, just apply style and you have an optimized, simple solution

Comment: I added to my question the arrays with the images of experiences... So In experiences component I add the code in steps 2 and 3, delete the const experience and create a child component in it?

Comment: It's only suggestion - Yes - instead of using useCallback - I suggest creating a child component - then you can map the experience list to a single experience. And the parameters that interest you - Photos and title, keep in an array that you loop - it gives such an advantage that you can add an infinite number of objects to this array, and the code will not need to be changed. By mapping the experience list, you pass on these two parameters - photo and title.

Comment: Sorry I still dont understand how it shows the other div with the images from my array over my current divs

Comment: Later in child component You have clicked state - and based on it you can render another component or another style - or add a new class to your div

Comment: So the Experience is what is shown after the click?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205694/discussion-between-piotr-zak-and-nanodine).